# Subsetting a dataframe in R with named vector giving undefined columns error

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am trying to extract specific columns from a dataframe using a defined named vector created beforehand. The vector looks like this -

```
>select_cols <- ids$test
>select_cols

01534314-832a-495f-99c2-40d9783401a2    053a0aff-7912-4f18-b997-d2f20d91bbf0     
            "TCGA-NH-A8F7-01A"                  "TCGA-DM-A288-01A"
```

My dataframe contains gene expression values for hundreds of samples, which looks like this

```
>exp.coad
                   ens.names TCGA-NH-A8F7-01A TCGA-DM-A288-01A TCGA-CA-5254-01A TCGA-5M-AAT5-01A TCGA-AA-3489-01A
ENSG00000000003.15    TSPAN6        13.067896        11.586922        11.022340        12.431234        11.768204
ENSG00000000005.6       TNMD         5.905824         4.061119         2.174923         6.898203         7.191496
ENSG00000000419.13      DPM1        11.677447        11.406170        11.355047        11.899990        11.245281
ENSG00000000457.14     SCYL3         9.226378         9.256162         8.972929         9.223441         9.316666
ENSG00000000460.17  C1orf112         8.472735         8.393176         8.039962         9.225961         8.731497
ENSG00000000938.13       FGR         6.745847         7.344758         7.014380         5.558205         9.901777
```

When I'm subsetting the dataframe using the following command

```
exp5 <- exp.coad[up, select_cols]), where up = dynamic value assigned in for loop
```

I am getting the following error -

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(exp.coad, up, select_cols) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

However, if I try to extract columns after explicitly mentioning it, I can get the desired dataframe

```
> exp.coad[up, c('TCGA-NH-A8F7-01A','TCGA-DM-A288-01A')]

                       TCGA-NH-A8F7-01A TCGA-DM-A288-01A
ENSG00000158769.18         12.64327         13.06597
```

I verified that the named vector is indeed a character datatype by doing

```
typeof(select_cols)

[1] "character"
```

Since I have to extract multiple columns in a loop, I can't explicitly mention column names every time. What could be the reason behind this error?

**Update**

I resolved the issue by using the following tweak -

`exp.coad[up, names(exp.coad) %in% select_cols]`

Comment: What does `select_cols %in% names(exp.coad)` return?

Comment: How is `ids` created? In particular, are you sure that dashes are just `-`?

Comment: `select_cols %in% names(exp.coad)` returns the following- `[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE `.     Just to clarify, select_cols is a larger vector than mentioned in the problem above, shorter example above is just for the sake of brevity .

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the error. You will have to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: `ids` is another dataframe from which I extract select_cols, based on a condition loop. How to check and make sure that dashed are just `-`

Comment: I have managed to make it work by using this tweak, based on the idea above -          
    `exp.coad[up, names(exp.coad) %in% select_cols]` .                                                    I am still not sure why the previous command is throwing up an error though.